# How to use a variable in a handlebars template attribute

Tags: javascript, class, handlebars.js

I am trying to set a variable on a handlebars attribute but it isn't being output.

```
const handlebars = require('handlebars');
const jamie = 'src-css-___grid__colTwoThree___1eBiI';

const search = handlebars.compile(`
<div class="grid">
  <div class="{{jamie}}">
  </div>
</div>
`);

export default search;
```

**Output**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="">
  </div>
</div>
```

How isn't jamie being output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to have three {{{ variable }}}.

Two for iterators like this

```
{{#each item}}
{{/each}}
```

Edit: If you're using ES6 you don't need handlebars.

```js
const jamie = 'src-css-___grid__colTwoThree___1eBiI';

const search = `
<div class="grid">
  <div class="${jamie}">
  </div>
</div>
`;

export default search;
```

Comment: Got excited then, still nothing on my end.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use handlebars? I would just use template literal strings with ${variable}

Comment: Hum I had thought about this, but then just though meh I'll go with handlebars :p but yem, good thinking :)

Comment: Thanks, here's a good link going over template literal strings, aka backticks https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/es6-template-literals/ easier to work with because you can throw in conditional logic like this <li>
        <span>${capitalize(person)}</span>
        ${isAdmin ?
          `<button>Delete ${capitalize(person)}</button>`
        : ''}
      </li>

Comment: Triple brackets worked for me, for accessing a variable within a quoted HTML attribute value using Handlebars.